# How to connect Selenium and AdBlock?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, automation, automated-tests

`

```
public class CucumberHooks {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

    }
    protected static WebDriver driver;

    @Before
    public void setup() throws IOException {
        ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
        options.addExtensions(new File("extension_5_3_2_0.crx"));
        DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
        capabilities.setCapability(ChromeOptions.CAPABILITY, options);
        String browser = ReadPropertyFileSingleton.getInstance().getProp("browser");
           driver = Util.setEnvironmentAndGetDriver(browser);
            assert driver != null;
            driver.manage().window().maximize();
            driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);


    }
    public static WebDriver getDriver() {
        return driver;
    }

    @After
    public void close() {
        driver.quit();
    }}
```

The code where I added adblock extensions via crx file
When I run tests through a feature file, a regular browser without a blocker is launched
the browser is also launched already with a blocker, but it does not see the steps
what could be the problem and is it possible to use adblock this way?

Comment: Doesn't seem like you are using your ChromeOptions object here.  You probably want an absolute path to the .crx file too...

Comment: When I put an absolute path I have IllegalArgumentException
and I don't know why
So, can use AdBlock with selenium for each scenario?

Comment: Don't do that "new File" bit... just send the path.

Comment: Could you please provide more details about why I shouldn't use "new File"
I deleted "new file" but still have the same problem

Comment: File is a class.  You'd use getAbsolutePath to get the path.  You can use the File class to check for existence of the file before sending the path, though, so it is useful.  The illegal argument error suggests that you're not sending the path for the .crx file.  Having said that, some extensions are not compatible with Selenium.  It's also not clear whether you are actually using the options./capabilities object here.  That stuff should probably be in your setEnvironmentAndGetDriver method.